# Add edges to scale-free network

Tags: r, random, igraph

This is my code:

```
network2 <- igraph::sample_pa(1000, m = 3, directed=F)
ecount(network2)
```

My goal is a network with 1000 vertices (done) and 3000 edges (I only get to 2994). Is there a way to add edges according to the Barabasi/Albert model and not just random edges?

Comment: FWIW, setting number of vertices to 1002 gives you 3000 edges ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for 1000 nodes and 3000 edges.

```
set.seed(1234)
g = sample_degseq(out.deg = rep(6,1000), method = "simple.no.multiple")
g
```

Comment: This creates a graph but it is not according to the Barabasi/Albert model... Still thank you!